# Why does this program in ><> (Fish) run so slow after a while?

Tags: performance, debugging, slowdown, esoteric-languages

The program `1+:o` in the esoteric programming language [><>](http://fishlanguage.com/) (Fish) slows down over time, and I don't know why. It slows down most on the `:`, which duplicates the item at the top of the stack, and slows down somewhat on the `o`, which prints out the corresponding character for the top item in the stack. You can try it out [here](http://fishlanguage.com/playground/j9694h7eaZ7LAdhti); just make sure to initialize the stack with a 0. It slows down faster on mobile devices (source: my phone), in case you want to check in less time.

Comment: On my computer, there is no slowdown up to ~1000. At which index do you see a slowdown? Have you consider using another interpreter? I don't think it's due to a feature of the language itself, looks more like an implementation problem.

Comment: The language's specs are here: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish

Answer (score 0):

never heard of this language before but here some possibilities:

1. your output is increasing

   - so each iteration you got 1 more character to show
   - if your brownser does not have some kind of smart refreshing
   - then this will slow down a lot for higher `n`
2. have no clue what you are doing as the language is foreign to me

   - but it looks like you are also increasing some array/stack/heap/whatever size
   - by one item each iteration which takes memory
   - and on phones there is not so much of it available
   - not to mention the relocations ...
3. the output looks like it is in Unicode

   - and once you hit the special characters then it depends on fonts installed
   - some characters are pretty slow.
   - Usual policy is to find used code page in installed fonts which could take a while
   - and the rendering itself is also for some characters not very good.
   - If you have some Unicode font (not just the chunks) then it should speed things up considerably (especially raster fonts).
   - But there are not many of them out there and never saw any that is complete (it wold be huge) but it is a while I search for those...
   - here one of the "complete" Unicode fonts example [GNU_Unifont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Unifont)

Answer (score 0):

I've programmed in ><> before, so I'll give my view on it.

Personally, I didn't experience much slowdown *of the program* when running it on my computer. I ran it *with* the animation, so I could see what was going on with the stack and execution speed.

The stack operations seem to occur at the same rate the entire time. I ran it past 3300. The *output* appears to slow down, but that it because the character sets for foreign languages use characters that combine or interact with each other in some way. This is the primary cause of the visual slowdown, as the output has to be rewritten as certain characters are printed adjacent to each other. So really, it's the fact that the memory usage increases the longer you run it, and the fact that the output is atypical.

Also, the RTL (right-to-left) character was printed, so all output following this character is displayed from right to left, which the browser isn't as used to and may not be optimized for.

Another way I can tell that the output is slowing down the browser is that when I pause execution of the program, the page is still slow. I tried to zoom in/out, and it took multiple seconds to render the output in some cases.